# Is it possible for a program to get number of spaces between command line arguments in POSIX?

Tags: shell, command-line, programming

Say if I wrote a program with the following line:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Now it knows what command line arguments are passed to it by checking the content of `argv`.

Can the program detect how many spaces between arguments? Like when I type these in bash:

```
ibug@linux:~ $ ./myprog aaa bbb
ibug@linux:~ $ ./myprog       aaa      bbb
```

Environment is a modern Linux (like Ubuntu 16.04), but I suppose the answer should apply to any POSIX-compliant systems.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why would your program need to know that?

Comment: @nxnev I used to write some Windows programs and I know it's possible there, so I wonder if there's something similar in Linux (or Unix).

Comment: I vaguely remember in CP/M that programs had to parse their own command lines - this meant that every C runtime had to implement a shell parser.  And they all did it slightly differently.

Comment: @iBug There is, but you need to quote the arguments when invoking the command. That’s how it’s done on POSIX (and similar) shells.

Comment: You seem to have a confused mere shells with system calls.

Comment: @iBug, ...Windows has the same design that Toby mentions from CP/M above. UNIX doesn't do that -- from the called process's perspective, there *is* no command line involved in running it.

Comment: I have read the answers and comments it seems that my answer and @KonradRudolph's comment are the only ones that tell you how to do it. The others may be technically correct, but are of no help to you, in solving your problem. If you want to know the number of spaces then you want to know. This is not windows, we should stop saying ”why do you want to do that, today?”

Comment: is "find out your own PID, and get the command line from ps" really impossible while POSIX compliant?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not meaningful to talk of "spaces between arguments"; that's a shell concept.

A shell's job is to take whole lines of input and form them into arrays of arguments to start commands with.  This may involve parsing quoted strings, expanding variables, file wildcards and tilde expressions, and more.  The command is started with a standard `exec` system call, which accepts a vector of strings.

Other ways exist to create a vector of strings.  Many programs fork and exec their own sub-processes with predetermined command invocations - in which case, there's never such a thing as a "command line".  Similarly, a graphical (desktop) shell might start a process when a user drags a file icon and drops it on a command widget - again, there's no textual line to have characters "between" arguments.

As far as the invoked command is concerned, what goes on in a shell or other parent/precursor process is private and hidden - we only see the array of strings that standard C specifies that `main()` can accept.

Comment: Good answer - it's important to point this out for Unix newbies, who often assume that, if they run `tar cf texts.tar *.txt` then the tar program gets two arguments and has to expand the second one (`*.txt`) itself. Many people don't realize how it really works until they start writing their own scripts/programs that handle arguments.

Comment: There are some OSes (hello, CP/M!) that do require each program to do its own globbing; even though there are libraries for that, you end up with a system full of programs linked with different libraries (or just different versions) and it becomes really hard to predict what each command will do.  I hope I never end up in that world again...

Answer (score 58):

In general, no. Command line parsing is done by the shell which does not make the unparsed line available to the called program. In fact, your program might be executed from another program which created the argv not by parsing a string but by constructing an array of arguments programmatically.

Comment: You may want to mention `execve(2)`.

Comment: You're right, as a lame excuse I can say that I'm currently using a phone and looking up man pages is a bit tedious :-)

Comment: [This](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) is the relevant section of POSIX.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner: Termux...? ;-)

Comment: "In general, no" would mean that there is some possible exception but it is definitely simply "no".

Comment: "in general" was meant as a safeguard against citing a special convoluted case where it is possible - for example, a suid root process might be able to inspect the calling shell's memory and find the unparsed command line string.

Comment: ...or perhaps writing a DEBUG trap in the shell that exports the original command as an environment variable. But still, the shell's cooperation or coercion is needed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I got that same idea. In Bash you could try `trap 'export CMDLINE=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG`. But it doesn't work, it appears to remove the extra white space before the string gets to `BASH_COMMAND`.

Comment: You're right. I'll admit to being surprised.

Answer (score 16):

No, this is not possible, unless the spaces are *part of* an argument.

The command accesses the individual arguments from an array (in one form or another depending on programming language) and the actual command line may be saved to a history file (if typed at an interactive prompt in a shell that has history files), but is never passed on to the command in any form.

All commands on Unix are in the end executed by one of the `exec()` family of functions.  These take the command name and a list or array of arguments. None of them takes a command line as typed at the shell prompt.  The `system()` function does, but its string argument is later executed by `execve()`, which, again, takes an array of arguments rather than a command line string.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I put that in there just in case there was some confusion about "spaces between arguments". Putting spaces in quotes between `hello` and `world` is _literally_ spaces between the two arguments.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Well, no... Putting spaces in quotes between `hello` and `world` is _literally_ supplying the second of three arguments.

Comment: @Jeremy As I said, in case there was any confusion about what was meant by "between the arguments". Yes, as a second argument _between_ the other two if you will.

Comment: Your examples were fine, and instructive.

Comment: Well, guys, the examples were an obvious source of confusion and misunderstanding. I have deleted them as the did not add to the value of answer.

Comment: [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is *documented* to fork a `/bin/sh -c` shell process

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, but what does `sh` use to run the command? It will use `execve()` to actually start the process.

Comment: Usually yes, but some shells have builtin commands (e.g. `echo` in bash) for which no `execve` is needed

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch A built-in command is not executed by `exec()`, true, but its command line is handled identically to that of any external command.

Answer (score 9):

In general, it is not possible, like several other answers explained.

However, [Unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) are *ordinary* programs (and they are interpreting the command line and [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) it, i.e. *expanding* the command before doing `fork` & `execve` for it).  See this [explanation about `bash` shell operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html#Shell-Operation). **You could *write your own shell*** (or you could patch some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) shell, e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)) and use it as your shell (or even your login shell, see [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) & [shells(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html)).

For example, you might have *your* own shell program put the full command line in some environment variable (imagine `MY_COMMAND_LINE` for example) -or use any other kind of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to transmit the command line from shell to child process-.

I don't understand why you would want to do that, but you might code a shell behaving in such a way (but I recommend not doing so).

BTW, a program could be started by some program which is *not* a shell (but which do [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) then [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), or just an `execve` to start a program in its current process). In that case there is no command line at all, and your program could be started without a command...

Notice that you might have some (specialized) Linux system without any shell installed. This is weird and unusual, but possible. You'll then need to write a specialized [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) program starting other programs as needed - without using any shell but by doing `fork` &  `execve` system calls.

Read also [*Operating Systems : Three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and don't forget that `execve` is practically always a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (on Linux, they are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), see also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html)) which reinitialize the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (and some other things) of the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) doing it.

Comment: This is the best answer. I assume (without having looked that up) that `argv[0]`  for the program name and the remaining elements for the arguments are POSIX specifications and cannot be changed. A runtime environment could specify `argv[-1]` for the command line, I assume ...

Comment: No, it could not. Read more carefully `execve` documentation. You cannot use `argv[-1]`, it is undefined behavior to use it.

Comment: Yeah, good point (also the hint that we have a syscall) -- the idea is a bit contrived. All three components of the runtime (shell, stdlib and OS) would need to collaborate. The shell needs to call a special non-POSIX `execvepluscmd` function with an extra parameter (or argv convention), the syscall constructs an argument vector for main that contains a pointer to the command line before the pointer to the program name, and then pass the address of the pointer to the program name as `argv` when calling the program's `main`...

Comment: No need to re-write the shell, just use  the quotes. This feature was available from the bourn shell `sh`. So is not new.

Comment: Using quotes require to *change* the command line. And OP don't want that

Answer (score 3):

You can always tell your shell to tell applications what shell code lead to their execution. For instance, with `zsh`, by passing that information in the `$SHELL_CODE` environment variable using the `preexec()` hook (`printenv` used as an example, you'd use `getenv("SHELL_CODE")` in your program):

```
$ preexec() export SHELL_CODE=$1
$ printenv SHELL_CODE
printenv SHELL_CODE
$ printenv  SHELL_CODE
printenv  CODE
$ $(echo printenv SHELL_CODE)
$(echo printenv SHELL_CODE)
$ for i in SHELL_CODE; do printenv "$i"; done
for i in SHELL_CODE; do printenv "$i"; done
$ printenv SHELL_CODE; : other command
printenv SHELL_CODE; : other command
$ f() printenv SHELL_CODE
$ f
f
```

All those would execute `printenv` as:

```
execve("/usr/bin/printenv", ["printenv", "SHELL_CODE"], 
       ["PATH=...", ..., "SHELL_CODE=..."]);
```

Allowing `printenv` to retrieve the zsh code that lead to the execution of `printenv` with those arguments. What you would want to do with that information is not clear to me.

With `bash`, the feature closest to `zsh`'s `preexec()` would be using its `$BASH_COMMAND` in a `DEBUG` trap, but note that `bash` does some level of rewriting in that (and in particular refactors some of the whitespace used as delimiter) and that's applied to every (well, some) command run, not the whole command line as entered at the prompt (see also the `functrace` option).

```
$ trap 'export SHELL_CODE="$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
$ printenv SHELL_CODE
printenv SHELL_CODE
$ printenv $(echo 'SHELL_CODE')
printenv $(echo 'SHELL_CODE')
$ for i in SHELL_CODE; do printenv "$i"; done; : other command
printenv "$i"
$ printf '%s\n' "$(printenv "SHELL_CODE")"
printf '%s\n' "$(printenv "SHELL_CODE")"
$ set -o functrace
$ printf '%s\n' "$(printenv "SHELL_CODE")"
printenv "SHELL_CODE"
$ print${-+env  }    $(echo     'SHELL_CODE')
print${-+env  } $(echo     'SHELL_CODE')
```

See how some of the spaces that are delimiters in the shell language syntax have been squeezed into 1 and how not the full command line is not always passed to the command. So probably not useful in your case.

Note that I would not advise doing this kind of thing, as you're potentially leaking sensitive information to every command as in:

```
echo very_secret | wc -c | untrustedcmd
```

would leak that secret to both `wc` and `untrustedcmd`.

Of course, you could do that kind of thing for other languages than the shell. For instance, in C, you could use some macros that exports the C code that executes a command to the environment:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define WRAP(x) (setenv("C_CODE", #x, 1), x)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (!fork()) WRAP(execlp("printenv", "printenv", "C_CODE", NULL));
  wait(NULL);
  if (!fork()) WRAP(0 + execlp("printenv",   "printenv", "C_CODE", NULL));
  wait(NULL);
  if (argc > 1 && !fork()) WRAP(execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]));
  wait(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ ./a.out printenv C_CODE
execlp("printenv", "printenv", "C_CODE", NULL)
0 + execlp("printenv", "printenv", "C_CODE", NULL)
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1])
```

See how some spaces were condensed by the C pre-processor like in the bash case. In most if not all languages, the amount of space used in delimiters makes no difference, so it's not surprising that the compiler/interpreter takes some liberty with them here.

Comment: When I was testing this, `BASH_COMMAND` didn't contain the original whitespace separating arguments, so this wasn't usable for the OP's literal request. Does this answer include any demonstration either way for that particular use case?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I just wanted to indicate the closest equivalent of zsh's preexec() in bash (as that's the shell the OP was refering to) and point out that it could not be used for that specific use case, but I agree it was not very clear. See edit. This answer is intended to be more generic about how to pass the source code (here in zsh/bash/C) that caused the execution  to the command being executed (not something that is useful, but I hope that while doing so, and especially with the examples, I demonstrates that it's not very useful)

Answer (score 0):

I will just add what is missing in the other answers.

## No

See other answers

## Maybe, sort of

There is nothing that can be done in the program, but there is something that can be done in the shell when you run the program.

You need to use quotes. So instead of

```
./myprog      aaa      bbb
```

you need to do one of these

```
./myprog "     aaa      bbb"
./myprog '     aaa      bbb'
```

This will pass a single argument to the program, with all of the spaces. There is a difference between the two, the second is literal, exactly the string as it appears (except that `'` must be typed as `\'`). The first one will interpret some characters, but split into several arguments. See shell quoting for more information. So no need to rewrite the shell, the shell designers have already thought of that. However because it is now one argument, you will have to do more passing within the program.

## Option 2

Pass the data in via stdin. This is the normal way to get large amounts of data into a command. e.g.

```
./myprog << EOF
    aaa      bbb
EOF
```

or

`./myprog`
*`Tell me what you want to tell me:`*
`aaaa      bbb`
`ctrl-d`

(Italics are output of program)

Comment: Technically, the shell code: `./myprog␣"␣␣␣␣␣aaa␣␣␣␣␣␣bbb"` executes (generally in a child process) the file stored in `./myprog` and passes it **two** arguments: `./myprog` and `␣␣␣␣␣aaa␣␣␣␣␣␣bbb` (`argv[0]` and `argc[1]`, `argc` being 2) and as in the OP's, the space that separates those two arguments is not passed in any way to `myprog`.

Comment: But you are changing the command, and OP don't want to change it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Following your comment, I read the question again. You are making an assumption. Nowhere does the OP say that they don't want to change the way the program is run. Maybe this is true, but they had nothing to say on it. Therefore this answer may be what they need.

Comment: OP ask *explicitly* about spaces *between* arguments, not about one single argument containing spaces